# Renci SSH.net changing remote SFTP port request C#

Tags: c#

I am writing a small piece of code in C# (VS 2017) to upload files to a remote server using SFTP through a SOCKS Proxy.

I have used Renci SSH.net before for other applications similar to this with no issues at all.

However in this application I am having an problem where the Renci SSH.net call to the Socks proxy is for a different Port to the one I requested.

Here is my code

```
private static void testSFTPConnection()
 {
        //get the SFTP Connection Info
        ConnectionInfo connInfo = testRemoteSFTP();           

        try
        {
            //Start the SFTP Client
            using (SftpClient remoteSFTPClient = new SftpClient(connInfo))
            {


                //Connect the remote session
                remoteSFTPClient.Connect();

                //log a successful connection
               Console.WriteLine("SFTP File Upload - connection to the file destination server successful");

                //Disconnect the Destination SFTP connection
                remoteSFTPClient.Disconnect();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SFTP File Upload Exception: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
public static ConnectionInfo testRemoteSFTP()
    {
        return new ConnectionInfo(remoteHost,50101, remoteUser,ProxyTypes.Socks5, proxyURL,proxyPort, proxyUser, proxyPwd, new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(remoteUser,remotePwd));

    }
```

As you can see I am setting the Connection info to call the remote host on port 50101 (as per their request) However when I run the code the SOCKS Proxy tells me I am requesting a connection to the remote server on Port 50297.

When I tried to debug the connection information in VS 2017, the connection object shows me the Port request as being 50101 but it still hits the proxy requesting port 50297

I used WinSCP to test the connection to the remote server through the SOCKS proxy on the port 50101 and it connected through fine.

I used wire shark to try and trap my outgoing connection request and there I can see the Port request has changed to 50297

I am now out of ideas as to what the cause of this could be or what fix to apply so any help in this regard would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: First thing is to probably download the source and figure out why, failing that if this is a bug it would seem better asked on the github issues page

Comment: read the source Luke